# Flattening a hierarchial data set in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a set of data as shown below

```
TREENAME DATE       LEVEL PARENTNODE    CHILDNODE
GRN_KK   9/1/2012   1     null          ALLACCOUNT
GRN_KK   9/1/2012   2     ALLACCOUNT     52000
GRN_KK   9/1/2012   2     ALLACCOUNT     59900
GRN_KK   9/1/2012   3     52000       54311
GRN_KK   9/1/2012   3     52000       50100
GRN_KK   9/1/2012   3     52000       54345
GRN_KK   9/1/2012   3     52000       54346
GRN_KK   9/1/2012   3     52000       54347
GRN_KK   9/1/2012   4     50100       50151
```

I need to flatten this data as below:

```
GRN_KK         9/2/2012     ALLACCOUNT           52000
GRN_KK         9/2/2012     ALLACCOUNT           52000      54311
GRN_KK         9/2/2012     ALLACCOUNT           52000      50100
GRN_KK         9/2/2012     ALLACCOUNT           52000      50100     50151
GRN_KK         9/2/2012     ALLACCOUNT           59900
```

And so on.

I can have up to 30 parent child relationship

I used the connect by and `sys_connect_by_path` as follows

```
    select A.TREE_NAME,A.EfFDT,A.PARENT_NODE_NAME,A.TREE_NODE, sys_connect_by_path(A.TREE_NODE, '/')
FROM PSTREENODE A
WHERE A.TREE_NAME = 'MDA_GRN_KK'
AND A.EFFDT = ( 
 SELECT MAX(A1.EFFDT) 
  FROM PSTREENODE A1 
 WHERE A.SETID = A1.SETID 
   AND A.SETCNTRLVALUE = A1.SETCNTRLVALUE 
   AND A.TREE_NAME = A1.TREE_NAME 
   AND A.TREE_NODE_NUM = A1.TREE_NODE_NUM 
   AND A.TREE_NODE = A1.TREE_NODE 
   AND A.TREE_BRANCH = A1.TREE_BRANCH 
   AND A1.EFFDT <= sysdate)
connect by nocycle prior  A.TREE_NODE = A.PARENT_NODE_NAME;
```

The result set is too large. There are other trees in this table and I don't think it just looks at the specified `TREE_NAME`. Its giving me all sorts of combinations.

Comment: if you have interconnections between trees you could add `AND A.TREE_NAME = 'MDA_GRN_KK'` into the `connect by clause` I guess

Comment: Why aren't you using `STARTING WITH`? Maybe you need `starting with parent_node = 'ALLACCOUNT'` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see tree `'MDA_GRN_KK'` then that's the "root" of your hierarchy. You specify the root using the `START WITH` clause. I normally put it right before the `CONNECT BY`:

```
... beginning of your query ...
START WITH A.TREE_Name = 'MDA_GRN_KK'
connect by nocycle prior  A.TREE_NODE = A.PARENT_NODE_NAME
```

Comment: I went a head and tried using Start with Tree_name. I still get over 50K records. When i look at the results this time i noticed that a level 2 node is showing up as /52000 and it is also showing this /ALLACCOUNT/52000

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding what your root node is. Can you try `START WITH ParentNode IS NULL`, and if that doesn't give what you need can you try `START WITH ParentNode = 'ALLACCOUNT'`?

Comment: I tried doing with both PARE_NODE_NAME is null and with Parent Node is allaccount. still getting 6000+ rows.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I have multiple trees using the same Parent node so for some reason it was not able to distinguish the trees. But when i took the data and put it in another table and ran the sql given by you. it worked perfectly. Do you know why its getting confused???

Comment: I'm not sure; I'd really have to see all the data to know - or maybe just some of the rows you got that you didn't expect to get. Did the multiple trees using the same parent by any chance explain the 6,000+ rows?

Comment: Yes it did explain why i was getting all kinds of combinations. But i atleast have a starting point in creating my application. I really appreciate the help